# How to save the process of your work in PRAAT?

Tags: phonetics, pronunciation, praat, prosody, intonation

Is it possible to save the process of your project (not a result of it) in PRAAT programme so that you can change smth later etc and do not do the same things over again?

Comment: What do you mean by "work" (in the title) and "project"? What functions in Praat are you using? What kinds of objects are you dealing with? You can always save all of the objects in your object window as a collection file.  Is that the kind of thing you're trying to do?

Comment: @musicallinguist Just as an observation (I'm also puzzled by the OP's question), I would avoid Collection objects at all costs unless they are a) essential and b) only contain non-Sound objects. Otherwise they can get really big, really fast, and do not allow for access to a subset of objects (you always have to open them as a whole).

Answer (score 2):

If by process you mean your transcription the answer is yes you can save your textgrids and load them back. about other works such as saving the sound selection you had like the picture below I must say No.

[image: praat]

Comment: tell me If I misunderstood your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I saved my work as a text grid, but how to put it into praat again?

By work, I mean the process, the constituents of the text grid or whatever the hell it is: the pitch, the divisions that I made, the names that I put etc!

Comment: This is not where more questions go. And the answer is 'load textgrid'.